# Javascript regex to disable shift, alt and ctrl keys

Tags: javascript, regex, keypress, onkeydown

I am using the following RegEx to disable all but numbers, comma and dot.

```
function isNumber(evt) {
    var theVal = $(evt).val();
    var theEvent = theVal || window.event;
    var key = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which;

    key = String.fromCharCode(key);

    if (key.length == 0) return;
    var regex = /^[0-9.,\b]+$/;

    if (!regex.test(key)) {
        theEvent.returnValue = false;
        if (theEvent.preventDefault) theEvent.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

And the HTML code:

```
<input type="text" id="number" onkeydown="isNumber($(this));" />
```

It works nicely but if I hold the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key down then I am able to input **letters and special characters** into the box which I do not want the user to be able to do.

What do I need to add to the RegEx above in order to block the <kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd> key as well?

Comment: do you have an excellent reason for not using `<input type="number">` like any sane developer would think in this situation?

Comment: You'd be surprised how complicated it can be to achieve what you want. Instead of re-inventing the wheel, I'd suggest using an existing plugin that already covers all the edge cases you'll run into: https://github.com/SamWM/jQuery-Plugins/tree/master/numeric

Comment: Why `isNumber($(this));` and not `isNumber(event);`?

Answer (score 6):

The reason it's not working is because SHIFT is a KEYDOWN event (shiftKey==true and keyCode==0), and when you press another key, a second event is triggered, which is why it is showing the symbols.

If you change the event to `onkeypress`, it should work.

Also, you don't need jQuery for this at all, see here:

https://jsfiddle.net/1569atLz/1/

**Warning:** People can still copy-n-paste into the edit box (unless you check for any change and not just key presses), so make sure to always validate server side as well when sending data! Anyone can easily press F12 and use the dev tools to force a change.

Comment: I found this to be accurate